# How to draw a Pixmap with partial transparency in GTK application

Tags: gtk

I'm just getting started with Mono programming using GTK, and have been pleasantly surprised.  However, I have come across a hurdle I haven't been able to get over yet.

In the app I'm working on, I am able to load a JPEG image into a Pixmap and draw it to my GUI's Drawing Area.  That works fine.  However, I want to be able to take a second JPEG image, make it partially transparent, and draw it over the first.  So far, I haven't been able to figure out a decent way to do this.

Is it somehow possible to change the alpha value of an entire Pixmap before I draw it?  I'm not sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `GtkDrawingArea` you should be using Cairo to do the drawing itself. As an alternative to using `cairo_paint()` there is a `cairo_paint_with_alpha()` which lets you specify the opacity you wish to paint with.

Comment: Thank you so much for that bit of insight.  I hadn't clued in to Cairo and how it fits in with Gtk.  That was just the clue I needed!  Thanks again!